# How to visualize /camera/depth/points without using rviz?

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Following this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros/Tutorials/CloudToImage) in the **Use ROS** there is a tutorial of how to visualize a point cloud, doing that I execute this commands:

```
$ roscore
$ rosrun openni_camera openni_node
$ rosrun pcl_ros convert_pointcloud_to_image input:=/camera/depth/points output:=/camera/depth/cloud_image
```

but i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1336450343.870410678]: Error in converting cloud to image message: No rgb field!!
```

This doesn't happen when I run this instead of my last line:

```
$ rosrun pcl_ros convert_pointcloud_to_image input:=/camera/rgb/points output:=/camera/depth/cloud_image</code></pre> <p>
I get no error and I do can visualize my image with:
</p> <pre><code>$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/cloud_image
```

It show this [image](https://encrypted-tbn1.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTiCbEEnorkkk-PIBLCEEe8N1VHqTCMfuZulBi9tKGo8V27WxYShw)

I can realize that command only accept point clouds from the rgb camera, but how can I visualize the depth images? (without using rviz)

P.S. I'm using ROS Electric, in Ubuntu 11.04

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33493/how-to-visualize-/camera/depth/points-without-using-rviz?/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-05-07**:
You get no output at all?

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2012-05-07**:
Sorry, it's fixed now

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2012-05-08**:
Any idea??

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-08**:
We could use some more information. What exact command results in that error? Can you get data from the individual topics in the `rostopic list` using `rostopic hz` or similar? What version of ROS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of using /camera/depth/points try using /camera/depth_registered/points as input argument. /camera/depth/points does not provide RGB data whereas /camera/depth_registered/points provides RGB data along with the depth data.

---

Originally posted by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) with karma: 156 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You converted it to an image, use image_view

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/cloud_image
```

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1